# Read a vector with floats with fstream

Tags: c++, vector, fstream

I have a paramaters.txt file that contains some paramaters to my OpenGL code, i need to read it and get them in a Matrix.

parameters.txt:

```
[6.0,6.0,9.0,5.0,1.0,0.6,0.4]
[3.0,1.0,3.0,6.0,1.0,0.4,0.6]
```

and here some code i did to transform the items ins the .txt to integers (when i was using integers)

flstream:

```
void selector() {
        int numberOfObjects = 0;
        char path[100];
    std::string my_list;
    //std::vector<std::vector<int>> parameters;
    std::cout << "Insira o Caminho Para As Especificações dos Solidos: "; //Insert the path to the especifications of the solids
    std::cin.getline(path, sizeof(path));
    std::cout << path;
    std::ifstream arquivo(path);
    std::string line;
    std::string vectors;
    if (arquivo.is_open()) {
        while (getline(arquivo, line)) {
            numberOfObjects ++;
            std::cout << line << std::endl;
            vectors.append(line);
        }
        arquivo.close();
    }
    parameters = matrix(vectors,numberOfObjects);
```

converter:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix(std::string vectors,int numberOfObjects){

    int teste = std::stoi (vectors,nullptr,10);

    int counter = 0;
    int numbers = 0;
    std::string chars = "[],";

    for(char c: chars){vectors.erase(std::remove(vectors.begin(), vectors.end(),c),vectors.end());}

    std::vector<char> v(vectors.length());
    std::copy(vectors.begin(), vectors.end(),v.begin());
    std::vector<int> convertedToInt;

    for(const auto& c :vectors)
        convertedToInt.push_back(c - 48);

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> result;

    result.resize(numberOfObjects);
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects ; i++){
        result[i].resize((convertedToInt.size()+1)/numberOfObjects);
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < convertedToInt.size(); j++){
        if(numbers == vectors.size()/numberOfObjects) numbers = 0;
        result[counter].at(numbers) = convertedToInt[j];
        if(numbers < vectors.size()/numberOfObjects) numbers++;
        if((j+1) % (vectors.size()/numberOfObjects) == 0) counter++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: We do not see a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not asking a question, I can only assume you do not know how to read a line from the posted file. Use the function below. This is how it works:

1. Read the first character from file. If we can't read or the character is not `'['`, return false – this is not a valid line.
2. While we can read a **number** and a **character** and the character is **comma**, add the number to the result vector.
3. The character after the last read number must be `']'`. If not, return false – this is not a valid line.
4. Add the last read number (the one before `']'`).
5. Return true – the line is valid.

*Welcome to SO and good luck!*

```
bool get_line( istream& is, vector<double>& v )
{
  char c;
  if ( !(is >> c ) || c != '[' )
    return false;

  double d;
  while ( is >> d && is >> c && c == ',' )
    v.push_back( d );

  if ( c != ']' )
    return false;

  v.push_back( d );

  return true;
}

int main()
{
  ifstream is{ "c:\\temp\\test.txt" };
  if ( !is )
    return -1;

  int lines_count = 0;
  for ( vector<double> v; get_line( is, v ); ++lines_count )
    /*...*/;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, i'm quite new in c++ and i was being beaten with these ifstream, you helped me in my College work, thanks very much sir.